# method requiring return statement outside for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, return, curly-braces

I'm encountering a problem on Eclipse with my method here. I am requried to return a `Country` object if the object is found in an array called catalogue and return null if it is not found. I attempted to iterate through the catalogue and do so. However java is requiring that I add a return statement outside the for loop of my code. However, when I add the return statement outside the for loop when the method is executed it ignores the for loop completely and only returns the statement outside the for loop.

```
public Country findCountry(String countryname) {
    for (int i = 0; i < catalogue.length; i++) {
        if (catalogue[i].getName() == countryname) {
            return catalogue[i];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Added foundCountry variable before the loop and returned it after. Added a break, and compared strings using .equals(). Getting a NullPointerException.

```
public Country findCountry(String countryname) {
        Country foundCountry = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < catalogue.length; i++) {
            if (catalogue[i].getName().equals(countryname)) {
                foundCountry = catalogue[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        return foundCountry;
    }
```

Comment: perhaps your `catalogue` array is empty. Or perhaps the issue is comparing Strings with == (use equals)

Comment: Note that you don't actually loop here, you always return on the first iteration. And what if the catalogue is zero-length? Move the `return null:` outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
catalogue[i].getName() == countryname
```

to

```
catalogue[i].getName().equals(countryname)
```

And don't `return null` from the `else` part. Do that when loop is completed and nothing is found like this:

```
public Country findCountry(String countryname) {
    for (int i = 0; i < catalogue.length; i++) {
        if (catalogue[i].getName().equals(countryname)) {
            return catalogue[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

*Note that its not **Null** proof.*

Answer (score 1):

Another version with stream usage (requires Java 8 or higher) and check for `catalogue` is not `null`:

```
public Country findCountry(String countryName) {
    if (catalogue == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return Arrays.stream(catalogue)
        .filter(country -> country.getName().equals(countryName))
        .findAny()
        .orElse(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
else {
            return null;
     }
```

and put this outside your for loop

```
return null;
```

Your code returns null if the country is not at the first element in catalog. It doesn't iterate through it.

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize the return value with null and only set it if found in the loop:

```
    public Country findCountry(String countryname) {
        // initialize a Country with null
        Country foundCountry = null;
        // try to find it
        for (int i = 0; i < catalogue.length; i++) {
            if (catalogue[i].getName().equals(countryname)) {
                // set it if found
                foundCountry = catalogue[i];
            }
        }
        // if not found, this returns null
        return foundCountry;
    }
```

Comment: using `==` for string comparison?

Comment: @ShanuGupta you're totally right, that is a thing not to do... I will correct it, haven't paid attention to that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
public Country findCountry(String countryname) {
        Country foundCountry = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < catalogue.length; i++) {
            if (catalogue[i].getName().equals(countryname)) {
              foundCountry = catalogue[i];
              break;
            }
        }
        return foundCountry;
    }
```

on found, break the loop to enhance performance.
On not found, by default it will return null.

Comment: I've added foundCountry before the loop and returned it after the loop, but i'm still getting a NullPointerException when i test the code. The class i use to test my code opens a text file and stores countries in the catalogue array so the array can't be empty.

Comment: looks like the countryname is not found/not present in catalogue.Does the text file have the same country which you passed as parameter for findCountry method? is catalogue an array of type Country?And getName() gets countryname?